# A Small Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb problem?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

I am facing an abnormal problem when *trying to write a rectangle with a color in PDF* using **Zend_PDF** as shown in the below diagram:
[image]

Code is as follow :

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
// register auto-loader
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
try 
{
    // create PDF
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
    // create A4 page
    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(133,185,13));
    $page->drawRectangle(40, 500, 560, 475);
    ...........................
    ...........................
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    die('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

***Issue :***

---

**Rectangle is their in the PDF But the color is not shown**. Also I tried to change some color code. And I found that ***if any one of the color code[i.e. R/G/B] is set to 0 then only the color is shown in the PDF doc.***

What may be the possible reason? Or I made any mistake?

Please help.!

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using in the proper way Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb

It get float for each of $r, $g, $b.
But will be a pain to figure it out the proper color using RGB anyway.
You can swich to HTML colors using this:

```
$page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Html('#cc0033'));
$page->drawRectangle(40, 500, 560, 475);
```

If you really want to go with Rgb check [Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Pdf/Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb.html)
and [Example page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html)

Comment: Yeah, Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb() expects values between 0 and 1. So if, like me, you tend to think in terms of 0...255 for RGB colors, simply divide your values by 255 when calling that method.